# Dynamically change isolated scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have the following directive:

```
.directive('compListRow', [listRow])
function listRow() {
    return {
            restrict: 'A',
            templateUrl: function($element, $attrs) {
                return $attrs.templateUrl || defaultTemplateUrl;
            },
            scope: true,
            controllerAs: 'listRow',
            bindToController: {
                collectionName: '@',
                modelId: '@',
                schedule: '='
            },
    ...
```

I want that the scope parameter can be dynamically set with an attribute of the directive (like the templateUrl). This is because sometimes i need the parent scope to be available and sometimes I need to have a fully isolated directive. Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

i think in that case you need to override your directive every time you need it because changing properties is not possible once defined but you can override it in a function call.

Comment: How can I do this?

Comment: redefine your directive in call of a function